# find each piece of data in string regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to seek out the following pieces of data from each line from the following lines, I will process each line individually.

Here are four lines that should cover every possibility of data it needs to analyze:

```
// lines to be analyzed
Chuck Norris (M) - 12/1/2009 (5 years)
Rocky Joseph Balboa (M) - 2/26/2012 (2 years)
Mary-Jane Smith (F) - 03/12/2012 (6 years)
Patricia Howser-Silverstine (F) 5/04/2009 (11 years)

// data to be extracted
First name: Chuck Last name: Norris Gender: M Birthdate: 12/1/2009
First name: Rocky Last name: Joseph Balboa Gender: M Birthdate: 2/26/2012
First name: Mary-Jane Last name: Smith Gender: F Birthdate: 03/12/2012
First name: Patricia Last name: Howser-Silverstine Gender: F Birthdate: 5/04/2009
```

I want to capture the first, last name, gender and birthdate for each line using regular expression, I will store each piece of data into a variable to be later inserted into a database table. I will need a list of regular expressions that would find each piece of data that I need.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what is considered a `First Name`? A first word only?

Comment: The first name is the first word, it can either be Rocky or Mary-Jane, one word or two words with a dash, like Mary-Jane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture all these values:

```
$re = '~^(?<fname>[\p{L}-]+)\h+(?<lname>[\p{L}\h-]+?)\h+\((?<gender>[MF])\)[-\h]+(?<dob>[\d/]+)~mu';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB2cE3/2)

Comment: I have upvoted this, but am confused why you have used the `m` modifier when he said he will process each line individually?

Comment: In that case `m` should be left out. Somehow I got impression that we are processing multiple lines block.

Comment: This solution doesn't handle middle names — for "Rocky Joseph Balboa", it returns "Joseph Balboa" as the last name.

Comment: People's names around the world can be very complex and no regex can cover all the edge cases. As long as it meets the requirements of OP it is fine I guess.

Comment: @anubhava I agree, if it meets the OP's requirements, it's fine. But he specifically included "Rocky Joseph Balboa" in his data, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: @Zac the Joseph Balboa is fine as the last name in this situation.

Comment: But OP wanted to capture `Joseph Balboa` as `lastName` and that's what this solution provides.

Comment: @anubhava You're right! Sorry, I assumed too much and read too little. :-D

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava's answer is correct, and meets the OP's requirement.

If middle names need to be matched (or thrown away), this variation uses an optional capture group to do the trick:

`^(?<fname>[\p{L}-]+)\h+(?:(?<mname>[\p{L}-]+)\h+)?(?<lname>[\p{L}\h-]+?)\h+\((?<gender>[MF])\)[-\h]+(?<dob>[\d/]+)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gB2cE3/4